# Why wp_nav_menu() doesnt show the proper meny when invoked two consecutive times?

Tags: theme-development, menus

I just noticed something weird I never saw before. I'm working on a project using WP 3.6.1. This project that has two different menus (actually, three, but that's not important). I'm calling them through the `wp_nav_menu` function.

I've done this kind of thing quite a few times now... but today is different. Today it doesn't work :(

My PHP code, placed in header.php, looks like this:

```
        <nav id="nav-menu-container">
            <div id="main-menu" class="main-menu menu clearfix">
                <?php wp_nav_menu('header_main'); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="secondary-menu" class="secondary-menu menu clearfix">
                <?php wp_nav_menu('header_secondary'); ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

The menu items are declared in `functions.php` and two different Menus are configured through the dashboard to show up in each location.

```
    if (function_exists('register_nav_menus')){
        register_nav_menu('header_main', 'Menú principal' );
        register_nav_menu('header_secondary', 'Menú secundario' );
    }
```

But the first menu keeps on being printed in the two locations. As I said above, using two different menu is something that Ive done in the past, but today I don't see the error... and there *is* and error, as it is not working :S

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) correctly.

You need to pass it an args array, and declare the `theme_location` key.

I'm assuming that, since you're passing a string rather than an array, `wp_nav_menu()` doesn't recognize the parameter, and is falling back to its default output:

> - the menu matching the ID, slug, or name given by the menu parameter, if that menu has at least 1 item;
> - otherwise, the first non-empty menu;
> - otherwise, output of the function given by the fallback_cb parameter (wp_page_menu(), by default);
> - otherwise nothing.

And you're seeing *the first non-empty menu* output in both locations.

Try this instead:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'header_main'
) ):
```

and

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'header_secondary'
) ):
```

Comment: thanks, I was adding an answer, i found the problem :) thanks @chip

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `wp_nav_menu` requires as input an associative array and i'm entering a raw string.

This code may work everywhere.

```
    <nav id="nav-menu-container">
        <div id="main-menu" class="main-menu menu clearfix">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'header_main') ); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="secondary-menu" class="secondary-menu menu clearfix">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'header_secondary') ); ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Sorry for the double post. It seems that the first menu was not appearing either, rather it was shown as a default option as no value was being passed at all.